# How to use Dependency Injection in Azure Function .NET 6?

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, config, blobstorage

I'm trying to upload files to an Azure Blob Storage. I want a C# Azure Function to be triggered by HTTP and then execute method `UploadAsync()`.

In order to connect to my storage account I need to create a `BlobContainerClient` and therefore I need to connect through a connection string. To not expose my connection string and to make my functionality mockable for testing, I want to setup my connection up with dependency injection.

[image]

However, I end up with the same error each time...

```
public interface IMyBlobService
{
    Task<bool> UploadImageAsync(Stream stream, string blobName);
}

public class MyBlobService : IMyBlobService
{
    private readonly BlobContainerClient _containerClient;

    public MyBlobService(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient)
    {
        _containerClient = blobContainerClient;
    }

    public async Task<bool> UploadImageAsync(Stream stream, string blobName)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = _containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
        var result = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);  
        // Do something with the result
    }

    public class MyBlobHandler
    {
        private readonly IMyBlobService _myBlobService;

        public MyBlobHandler(IMyBlobService myBlobService)
        {
            _myBlobService = myBlobService;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Handle(Stream stream, string blobName)
        {
            return await _myBlobService.UploadImageAsync(stream, blobName);
        }
    }
```

---

Startup.cs

```
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = BuildConfiguration(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath);
            builder.Services.AddAppConfiguration(configuration);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
            {
                var connectionString = builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetConnectionString("Storage:ConnectionString");
                return new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "pictures");
            });

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyBlobService, MyBlobService>();
        }

        private IConfiguration BuildConfiguration(string applicationRootPath)
        {
            var config =
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(applicationRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
            return config;
        }
    }
    internal static class ConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddAppConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.Configure<StorageSettings>(config.GetSection(nameof(StorageSettings)));
            return services;
        }
    }
```

I figured out *(with commenting other stuff out)* that:

> var configuration =
> buildConfiguration(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath);

### is causing the error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
How do I fix this?

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "StorageSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol... etc etc"
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out a way to make this work properly.

It seems like dependency injection works differently for Azure Functions?

Documentation about DI like (e.g.): https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/azure-functions/dotnet/2022/05/10/use-settings-json-azure-function-en.html got me started but I have spent more than 6 hours trying now.

Can someone with more expertise share some thoughts?

UPDATE: My system doesnt know my settings file and therefor throws a nullexception. How can I add this to iniate my BlobContainerClient properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration, the `BlobContainerClient` should be added as a singleton, you didn't added the `IMyBlobService` in the DI container

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
        {
            var connectionString = builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyBlobStorage");
            return new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "mycontainer");
        });

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyBlobService, MyBlobService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with your Configure method. It cannot read my connectionstring from file "appsettings.Development.json. I get the following error:"System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: UploadFileToStorage. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').

Comment: Make sure you have the connection string inside the appsettings in the format: `{  "ConnectionStrings": {"MyBlobStorage": "my_connection_string"}}`

Comment: I've added my file to the question. It does not read the value from the settings. I have commented out my ConfigureAppConfiguration because it gives me the following error: ImageFunction: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. System could not find the file.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: It will only works if the environment variable is Development

Comment: I just added some information regarding that the error is thrown by the BuildConfiguration method

Comment: Its a different question google it

Comment: Since the problem for BlobService should be solved I will accept the answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of Shahar Shokrani I could add my BlobService with his code snippet:

```
   public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
            {
                var connectionString = builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyBlobStorage");
                return new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "mycontainer");
            });
    
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyBlobService, MyBlobService>();
        }
    }
```

Also, for people having the same problem after me: **CHECK YOUR NUGET PACKAGES!**
Make sure that you do not use: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`.
A project in my solution used this and I have struggled for two days.